# Tile based enclosure checking algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

For my c++ game, I'm attempting to detect when any number of tiles is completely surrounded by walls, each time a wall is placed.  I'm curious to know if anyone's ever done this before, or if anyone knows of any algorithms that would do it.

Unfortunately, Google hasn't been very helpful with my keywords.

EDIT: It seems flood fill is what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  What does "placing a wall" involve?  And what do you mean by "any number of tiles"?

Comment: How do you represent the map (tiles, walls)? I'm not sure if this algorithm has a name: simply iterate over all tiles, check its walls and check if it is surrounded.

Comment: Assuming your space is one-dimensional and connected: All but the outer two tiles are completely walled in. There you go, a simple algorithm!

Comment: Is a flood-fill from the outside too slow? There are faster ways, but they're more work to implement.

Comment: Basically, the player places walls, and when they enclose an area, that area becomes theirs.

Comment: Assuming that 'claimed area' cannot be divided and claimed by another player: Each tile starts at 0. Each time a tile has a wall around it, increment it. When a tile gets a neighbor that is marked, increment it; if a wall is placed on that same side, do not increment. An enclosed area represents a consecutive run of 4's out to the edge (which has a spare '0' row for algorithmic purposes). An exclusion list is kept to simplify checking already-claimed areas.

Comment: To clarify a bit, by 'marked' I meant another tile of any number other than 0

Comment: This game has been done before. It's called "go".

Comment: In fact, mark any 'claimed' tiles as 5, and ignore them. When you're doing a search, follow a raster pattern and make sure each run of 4's overlaps at least 1 tile; you will find an enclosed area when, like I said, it's all 4's.

Comment: Of course, you don't actually check every time a wall is placed, just when the wall joins another wall on both ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to [flood-fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to check which squares are still accessable after a wall was added.

Comment: Yep. I suppose I'll do a flood fill on the outside, and then invert the fill data, allowing me to see where the contained patches are.  Then I'll do a few more to find who owns what.  Maybe that's too slow for each piece?  I'm planning on ~2 pieces per second with 4 players.

Comment: @roadkillguy What is the sizw of the board? unless we are talking millions of squares, this is not really an issue.

Comment: The max will probably be around 64x64 or so.  Not really that big.